# multiple style values inside a view

Tags: android

I have 2 styles defined inside styles.xml. I want to apply it to a textview. How to implement that using style = "@style/"

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't. You will have to create a style which combines the two styles. (Or create just one style that inherits from one of your styles, and add the extra data of the second style).

Comment: any code will helpful

Answer (score 20):

You can make a style that inherit the other style

For example:

```
<style name="Side_Menu_Button" parent="android:attr/buttonStyleSmall">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Where the side_menu_button inherit from all the attribute of buttonStyleSmall

Comment: if you want to use own styles you write "@styles/mystyle" instead of android:attr

Comment: sorry but buttonStyleSmall is one of the default android style

Comment: Personally I think this is the best answer. I have a "StandardViewSize" style, inherited by "StandardButton", in turn inherited by a "LoginButton". Essentially a whole tree of styles, starting as generic as possible and combining them into more specific component styles to create a unified look and feel.

Comment: I used [`parent="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7168165/6243352) instead of the `android:attr...` shown here.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround that can work in some situations, you can wrap your target view with LinearLayout and assign one style to the layout another to the view:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="@style/padding">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bold text with padding"
    style="@style/text_bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Won't work, applying a style to a containing layout doesn't affect the inner layouts

Comment: @tbkn23 it doesn't have to affect the inner layouts. For example you want to change the background or add a border, this can be done on the parent layout.

Comment: @tbkn23 highly dependent on what you want to do. Lets say style A sets background color and dimensions, while style B sets text color and size. Then you can use style A on layout and B on TextView. That's why the examples are named as they are.
That being said, it seems like very bad practice that can be better achieved with the other proposed answers. As a general rule, creating a whole view instance just to set an additional style that could be applied directly otherwise is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

This is a hack that I got to work:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Title.App" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text_default_material_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.TV" parent="TextView.App">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Other.App</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the particular case of a Button and other Views which support the textAttribute attribute, you can divide the two styles into a Button specific style which would be assigned to attribute:style and a Text specific style which would be assigned to `attribute:textAppearance`. Note though, that attributes defined in `attribute:style` will override values defined in `attribute:textAppearance`.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm 10 years late but I came across this problem myself and found a solution for it albeit it's quite a workaround.

To get started you need to declare styleable attributes to assign to your view later on

```
<declare-styleable name="TextView">
    <attr name="style1" format="reference" />
    <attr name="style2" format="reference" />
    <attr name="style3" format="reference" />
    <attr name="style4" format="reference" />
    <attr name="style5" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

You can just add these style attributes to your view within the layout like

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/nice_cta"
    app:style1="@style/Background_Blue"
    app:style2="@style/CallToAction.Primary"
    app:style3="@style/Button_Layout" />
```

To make it work you need to implement a custom `ViewInflater` that you assign to your application's theme under `viewInflaterClass`. Inside this `ViewInflater` you collect the styleable attributes and merge them into a `theme` as follows:

```
class MultiStyleViewInflater : MaterialComponentsViewInflater() {
    // override the creators of any view you want to have multiple styles
    override fun createTextView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): AppCompatTextView {
        // create context if needed and set the attributes as usual
        return super.createTextView(createContextIfMultiStyle(context, attrs), attrs)
    }
    
    // override fun anyOtherView as needed ...

    private fun createContextIfMultiStyle(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): Context {
        // get our handy custom attributes
        val styleAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextView)
        
        // collect the styles added to the view
        val styles = extractStyles(styleAttributes)
        
        // create the custom ContextThemeWrapper only if the view has a custom multi style attribute
        val createdContext = if (styles.any { it != 0 }) {     
            // create a theme, add styles and create the wrapper using the theme
            val theme = context.resources.newTheme()
            
            theme.applyValidStyles(styles)
            ContextThemeWrapper(context, theme)  
        } else {
            // or just return the original context
            context
        }
        
        // don't forget to call this!
        styleAttributes.recycle()
        
        return createdContext
    }

    private fun extractStyles(styleAttributes: TypedArray) = listOf(
        // the zero values help us determine if we have a custom style added at all
        styleAttributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.TextView_style1, 0),
        styleAttributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.TextView_style2, 0),
        styleAttributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.TextView_style3, 0),
        styleAttributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.TextView_style4, 0),
        styleAttributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.TextView_style5, 0)
    )

    private fun Resources.Theme.applyValidStyles(styles: List<Int>) {
        // adding styles that actually exist. note we force update duplicate attributes
        styles.filterNot { it == 0 }.forEach { this.applyStyle(it, true) }
    }
}
```

To make this your app theme's `ViewInflater` add this line to it:

```
<item name="viewInflaterClass">com.agostonr.multistyleapp.utils.MultiStyleViewInflater</item>
```

After this if you build your application the styles should show up in the editor as well as on the running app on your device.

For a more detailed explanation see the article I wrote about it [on Medium](https://romhanyia.medium.com/assign-multiple-styles-to-a-single-view-in-android-just-like-in-css-815040be4c2b).