# In Android XML, can I set buttonStyleSmall or Button.Small as a parent style to a custom style?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

I want to extend Android's small button style. I can do it inline:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/myButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="Click Here"/>
```

But in the interest of reusability, I want to transfer these styles to a custom style. How can I add `buttonStyleSmall` (or `Widget.Button.Small`?) as a parent to a style? Something like this in my custom style XML:

```
<style name="RightLink" parent="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall">
  <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
  <item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
</style>
```

with the button declaration using that style:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/myButton"
        style="@style/RightLink"
        android:text="Click Here"/>
```

**EDIT**

Using the correct syntax as described by Lukas below (use `@android:attr/buttonStyleSmall` as the parent), I'm still seeing a difference between the two:

Button with buttonStyleSmall as style and inline styles added:

[image: pic1]

Custom style with buttonStyleSmall as the parent:

[image: pic2]

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, what is the entire solution for this? Can you post full code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So you try to [inherit style informations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance) from a standard Android style. For this, you'll need to use the `parent`-attribute as you already did.

The only exception when inheriting a standard style is, that you have to use an `@` not a `?`:

```
<style name="RightLink" parent="@android:attr/buttonStyleSmall">
```

A little more about how to do that for platform styles (because that differs from styles you created yourself) can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles).

---

After playing around with it i found that the way you inhirate is correct, but the recourse is wrong:

```
<style name="RightLink" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small">
```

This works.

The difference seams to be that the integer-constant which is used to add this by using the `style`-attribute and in code is declared in Androids `R`-class in the `attr`-subclass.

The XML-Style definitions (from which you can actually inherit) are stored in the `style`-subclass of the `R`-class. So the above line should solve your problem.

Comment: so I'm confused, is <style name="RightLink" parent="@android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"> still a valid line? Android Studio says it is not.

Comment: @DanielOchoa I haven't tried it since, if it compiles, you should be fine.

Comment: Same as @DanielOchoa, says it 's not a valid line

Comment: `<style name="RightLink" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small">` was fine, but I wasted some time messing with `<style name="RightLink" parent="@android:attr/buttonStyleSmall">` which gave an invalid parent reference.